# Access json data using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am finding difficult to access json data like this.
If this is my json data. How can I access this in html using angularjs with ionic framework.

```
{"status": "OK",    
 "message": "OK",
"data": {
"total": 116,
"params": [],
"heading": "Psychology Blog, Total 116",
"sub_option": "blog",
"text1": "Read more",
"rows": [
  {
    "post_id": "124",
    "user_id": "1443980348",
    "post_type": "post",
    "post_format": "text",
    "post_name": "is-money-most-important-in-life-",
    "post_title": "Is Money most Important in life?",
"alt_text": "alt=\"\" /></span></p>"
  },
  {
    "post_id": "122",
    "user_id": "1443980348",
    "post_type": "post",
    "post_format": "text",
    "post_name": "should-divorcing-parents-make-their-child-choose-",
    "post_title": "Should divorcing parents make their child choose?",
"alt_text": "alt=\"\" /></p>"
  }
]
"paging": {
  "now": 100,
  "next": 2,
  "page": 1,
  "limit": 100,
  "start": 0,
  "total": 116,
  "limitstart": 0,
  "nowTotal": 100
}
}
}
```

this is my angularls

```
.controller('show_post', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.display_post = function () {
    var request = $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "url here......",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });
    request.success(function (data) {
        $scope.post=data;
    });
}
})
```

i tried using ng-repeat but it did not work out. Please help.

Comment: Post how you used ngRepeat?

Comment: <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="x in post">
              {{ x.data.rows.post_name}}
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hell everyone, 
I've got the answer.
The approache that we can use to access json data like stated above(in the form of multidimensional array).

1st approach: In your controller
add

`var yourVariable = data['data']['rows'];
$scope.htmlVariable = yourVariable;`

and in your html add

```
<div ng-repeat="x in htmlVariable"><p>{{x.id}}</p></div>
```

this might be helpful to others, and i would like to thank all the people for their great response.

Answer (score 0):

Change the content-type  of header

From

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

To

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

This will solve your problem.

You can display the data as,

```
<div ng-repeat="r in post.rows">  {{r.post_id}} , {{r.post_title}}</div>
```

Comment: after modifying how can i access in html. can you send me a dummy code.

Comment: Let say you want to access status and message,

Comment: Please do for post_id and post_title

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Comment: any problem with my js code except which you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

## PostsController

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('PostsController', PostsController);

    function PostsController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.posts = [];

        //activating controller
        activate();
        function activate() {
            // using $http directly on Controller is a bad idea;
            // create a Service
            $http.get('your url')
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.posts = [].concat($scope.posts, response.data.rows)
                    // according to your data provided
                })
        }
    }
})();
```

### posts.view.html

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
   <h4>post.title</h4>
   .........

</div>
```